# Google Pay country not supported

Tags: google-pay

My Google Play country used to be France. I changed it to USA, and can use Google Play myself, but I can't set up Google Play Family Library: "Country not supported. Confirm the country associated with your account in Google payments > Settings."

I have two payment methods, but one is expired. The expired card might belong to a relative in France, but I can't find a way to delete the expired card, only update its expiration date.

Note: my address under Payments Profile is a U.S. address.

Note: I see a link to "Close payments profile". If I do that, can I keep my gmail account and open a new payment profile associated with it?

[image: The "Get Started" link for Google Family Library says "Country Not Supported"]

[image: Country is United States]

[image: I suspect that the expired card is a French card]

Comment: Did you change your country in the Google Play app under *Settings > General > Account and device preferences > Country and profiles* or some where else? As far as I understand: to be able to do that, you need to wait 12 months after adding a payments profile (on pay.google.com) with your new country.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you come up with a solution?